# Add the loop index with variable, array & table names in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have the following code:

```
inter = [5 10 15 20 25];

for q = 1:size(inter)
    judgments = inter(q);
    pc5{1,2}=[]; 
            for r=1:height(pc64Video) 
               mnew5 =  pre(datasample(find(strcmp(pre.video, pc64Video.video(r))), judgments, 'Replace', false),:); 
               pc5(end+1,:) = {'abc',1, mnew5,judgments};
               pc5_r = cell2table(all_models_by_category);
          end 
end
```

Please do not look at how right the code is but what i want,
 
The above code contains **variable, array and table** names for examples mnew5, pc5, pc5_r. 
I want to replace '5' with the 'q' index number(like `pc5, pc10, pc15..` `pc5_r, pc10_r,..` `mnew5, mnew10,mnew15.. etc`) 
i tried like this: `nvar = eval(['pc', num2str(q)])` but it did not work
Can any one please help me with this?

Comment: Horrible horrible idea! Do you have a really _**good**_ reason for doing this?

Comment: yes, i have huge number of different types of data which i want to save in different variable, arrays and tables.

Comment: Check the dupe. Apart from this, I believe @StewieGriffin just wanted to give you a friendly advice. What you tries to do is definitely a terrible idea. There are clean ways to do this which can, should and _is supposed to_ be used instead. These involve structs and/or cells. Good code is analyzed statical in as high extent as possible. If possible, avoid evaluate code in runtime. Otherwise, if you give this code to someone else you will have to consider getting one of these cages that those cutting the driving range grass has. And you will probably hate your code sooner or later.

Comment: ok thanks for your advices. but i at least need to change a table name: `pcX_r , X= loop index number`